# text field filled out on ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I'm looking to have the State and Zip_code values filled out on my ajax call.  Instead of having it in txtzip.  I would like the State and Zip_Code fields filled with values from txtzip

Here's my attempts so far:

```
<input type="text" name="State" id="State" placeholder="NY" value="" size="5"/>
<input type="text" name="Zip_Code" placeholder="zip code" value="" size="10" />
<div id="txtZip"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

**Ajax code**

```
function showZip(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtZip").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtZip").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Getzip.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP code**

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Leadbook", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Zip WHERE City = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  $State = $row['State'];
  $Zip_Code = $row['Zip Code'];

  $info[] = array( 'State' => $State, 'Zip Code' => $Zip_Code );
  }
echo json_encode($info);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**Question:** How can I do this?

Comment: instead of innerHTML use value. Like
document.getElementById("Zip_code").value=xmlhttp.responseText;

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the selector for `Zip_code` in this two lines:

```
document.getElementById("Zip_code").innerHTML="";

document.getElementById("Zip_code").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Resulting in:

```
function showZip(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("Zip_code").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Zip_code").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Getzip.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I changed it...still don't workfunction showZip(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("Zip_Code").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Zip_code").setAttribute("value",xmlhttp.responseText)
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Getzip.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

Comment: Ok..i have it working..but it's putting the State field with the Zip_Code Field...i'm looking to seperate them...thanks

Comment: i changed the array  $info[] = array( $State, $Zip_Code );